# How to dynamically create controls aligned to the top but after other aligned controls?

Tags: delphi, controls, alignment, delphi-xe2

In this particular case I'm using [PowerPDF](http://www.est.hi-ho.ne.jp/takeshi_kanno/powerpdf/) library to dynamically build a PDF document, but the same applies for the general concept of dynamically aligning controls sequentially inside of a parent control. In this library, `TPRPage` is the base control to contain all element controls, in this case, sequential instances of `TPRLayoutPanel`.

What I do when dynamically adding controls:

1. Create a control (`TPRLayoutPanel`)
2. Set the control's parent (`TPRPage`)
3. Align the control to top (`PRLayoutPanel.Align:= alTop;`)

The problem is it gets forced to the very beginning (top) instead of the very end (bottom) of the page.

I've tried setting its order `PRLayoutPanel.SendToBack;` or `PRLayoutPanel.BringToFront` but with no luck.

How can I dynamically create and align multiple controls within a parent control sequentially? My only current work-around is to add the controls in reverse order (from end to beginning) which is ridiculously unnecessary.

Here's my universal function which creates every new instance of an aligned control in this parent:

```
function TfrmReport.InsertPanel: TPRLayoutPanel;
begin
  Result:= TPRLayoutPanel.Create(PRPage);
  Result.Parent:= PRPage;
  Result.Align:= alTop;
  Result.Height:= 40; //Default, may change later
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `Top` property to be the bottom of the previous panel. For example, like this:

```
PanelTop := 0;
for i := 0 to 5 do
begin
  Panel[i] := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel[i].Parent := Self;
  Panel[i].Height := PanelHeight;
  Panel[i].Align := alTop;
  Panel[i].Top := PanelTop;
  inc(PanelTop, PanelHeight);
end;
```

To fit it into your code you'd have to keep track of the location of the most recently added panel. Perhaps you could add a `var` parameter to your `InsertPanel` function:

```
function TfrmReport.InsertPanel(var PanelTop: Integer): TPRLayoutPanel;
begin
  Result:= TPRLayoutPanel.Create(PRPage);
  Result.Parent:= PRPage;
  Result.Top:= PanelTop;
  Result.Height:= 40;
  Result.Align:= alTop;
  inc(PanelTop, Result.Height);
end;
```

I trust you get the idea!

Comment: Nice, that `var` parameter! +1

Comment: Important calling order: Panel[i].Top := PanelTop; and then Panel[i].Align := alTop; Otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 22):

Once again, [`DisableAlign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DisableAlign) and [`EnableAlign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.EnableAlign) to the rescue:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  P: TPanel;
begin
  DisableAlign;
  try
    for I := 0 to 4 do
    begin
      P := TPanel.Create(Self);
      P.Caption := IntToStr(I);
      P.Align := alTop;
      P.Parent := Self;
    end;
  finally
    EnableAlign;
  end;
end;
```

#### Explanation:

When alignment is **enabled**, every single addition of a control to a container (the form itself in this specific case) will re-evaluate all alignment (and anchor) settings of all other controls within that container. In case that control has no specific `Top` property set, then `Top` will be `0`. When there is already another control aligned to the top, then there are two controls with `Top = 0`, and the one which is about to inserted wins. I (currently) have no in-depth explanation for that, but it just is, and the position order indeed gets reversed from the creation order.

Now, when alignment of the container is **disabled**, then consecutive added controls are simply just inserted with all their positioning properties unaltered. When alignment is enabled again, then all those controls are re-evaluated in the same manner, with the difference that this takes place in one single loop in the order of the index in the `Controls` array; i.e. the order in which they were created.

Comment: Simply Brilliant, and perhaps the appropriate answer, since it appears to have been created for this exact reason.

Comment: Why exactly does this work? How is the ordering enforced when EnableAlign is called? Would this work if we added one control at a time? And presumably you need to call `DisableAlign` and `EnableAlign` on the same control that is being assigned to `P.Parent`?

Comment: @David I will expand on that in the answer.

Comment: This was life saver for me. I have a tricky form with multiple panels and splitters that can be hidden and the alignment order was driving me crazy. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use alCustom align type and control all of your panels positions via CustomAlignPosition method (you will need to override it in parent control). This will give you more flexibility and control.

Comment: This hardly flexible. It forces you to derive a new type. And then write a load code to do the work.