# Delphi XE4 dynamic panel alignment order

Tags: delphi, alignment, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have a Firemonkey app. that dynamically adds a number of objects derived from a TPanel with

```
 Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
```

However, the last object ends up at the top, with all the others in the correct place.

e.g.

```
Panel-5
Panel-0
Panel-1
Panel-2
Panel-3
Panel-4
```

when I want

```
Panel-0
Panel-1
Panel-2
Panel-3
Panel-4
Panel-5
```

I've tried alBottom, alMostTop[ etc but all have a similar problem.

How can I fix thgis?

Cheers,

Martin.

Comment: Have you tried giving each panel a "head start". When I do this kind of thing I always set the .Top property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now as official answer:
When creating your panels assign a value for top (the height of the container, for example). 
Reason:
When you create a component its top will always be 0. With two components with a top at 0 and alTop it is purely coincidental which component ends up on top in the end. See here for some code doing the trick: [How to dynamically create controls aligned to the top but after other aligned controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623347/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-aligned-to-the-top-but-after-other-aligned-co)

Comment: I'll give that a go thanks. I got a workaround by putting a panel height=1 on at designtime which seems to have worked.