# Dynamic Create and Align Labels in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, dynamic, components, firemonkey

I make this procedure that create dinamic TLabel Object into one TLayout component in my firemonkey form.

```
procedure TForm1.printinLayout14(const str: String);
var
  P:TLabel;
begin
  P:=TLabel.Create(Self);
  P.parent:=Layout14;
  p.Align:=TAlignLayout.alTop;
  p.Text:=str;
  p.AutoSize:=true;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

In my code I call this procedure in the next way

```
printinLayout14('l1');
printinLayout14('l2');
printinLayout14('l3');
printinLayout14('l4');
```

the expected result would be:

```
---
l1
---
l2
---
l3
---
l4
---
```

but the final result is

```
---
l1
---
l4
---
l3
---
l2
---
```

How I can fix it?. Iam using Delphi Xe3

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Solved it.

Solution:
According to @ NGLN in
[How to dynamically create controls aligned to the top but after other aligned controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623347/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-aligned-to-the-top-but-after-other-aligned-co)

> When there is already another control aligned to the top, then there are two controls with Top = 0, and the one which is about to inserted wins.

So to avoid this I assign manually a Position.Y  property different #0 before ALign:=alTop for any new child created inside the TLayoutComponent in this way:

```
p.Position.Y:=p.Widht*(Layout14.ChildrenCount-1);
p.Align:=TAlignLayout.alTop;
```

Comment: Your interpreted solution is just a lucky hit. You use the width instead of height and the hope, that every child has the same height

Comment: You cound just set a very high number in Position.Y (e.g. 2000) and get the same effect.

Comment: @MikeSutton Best value for this is `System.Math.MaxSingle` :o)