# Draw TPanel and TSplitter at runtime results in wrong component order

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

If I create multiple TPanel and TSplitter components at runtime into a TScrollBox, the order of the components is wrong. If I call drawInput() 3 times, the scrollbox contains 3 panels followed by 3 splitters instead of 1 panel followed by 1 splitter (repeated).

How can I force the correct order?

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUTp9.jpg)

```
function drawInput(owner: TWinControl): TWinControl;
var
  panel: TPanel;
  edit: TEdit;
  splitter: TSplitter;
begin
  panel := TPanel.Create(owner);
  panel.Parent := owner;
  panel.Align := alTop;
  panel.AlignWithMargins := True;
  panel.BorderWidth := 0;
  panel.Color := clRed;
  panel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  panel.ParentBackground := False;
  panel.Ctl3D := False;

  edit := TEdit.Create(panel);
  edit.Parent := panel;
  edit.Align := alTop;
  edit.AlignWithMargins := True;
  edit.Text := 'foo';
  edit.Margins.Left := 5;
  edit.Margins.top := 5;
  edit.Margins.Bottom := 5;
  edit.Margins.Right := 5;

  splitter := TSplitter.Create(owner);
  splitter.Parent := owner;
  splitter.Align := alTop;
  splitter.Beveled := True;
  splitter.Height := 3;
end;
```

**EDIT:**

Here is how I call this function:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  form: TForm;
  sb: TScrollBox;
begin
  form := TForm.Create(Application);
  sb := TScrollBox.Create(form);
  sb.Parent := form;
  sb.Align := alClient;
  sb.Color := clBlack;
  drawInput(sb);
  drawInput(sb);
  drawInput(sb);
  drawInput(sb);

  form.Width := 300;
  form.Height := 700;
  form.ShowModal;
end;
```

Comment: You can try to assign explicitly `TOP` property of the splitter: `splitter.Top := panel.Top + panel.Height`

Comment: In past, I was using rxSplitter or dxSplitter, which had additional properties like `FirstPanel` and `SecondPanel`, and this solved problems.

Comment: In fact, you are *inserting those components to top*. So as expected behavior should be that the splitters are on top.

Comment: But the splitters are not on top but after the 4 panels.

Comment: I see (I could reproduce the problem). So you want that splitter above the panel ? I'm asking because that's what your code would produce (if alignment worked properly).

Comment: See [How to dynamically create controls aligned to the top but after other aligned controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623347/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-aligned-to-the-top-but-after-other-aligned-co/15625706#15625706)

Comment: Tip: Don't name a routine Draw when it Creates.

Comment: TLama: After each of the 4 panels there should be a splitter (as sep. between two panels).

Comment: Strange. This seems like a bug in XE5. Here with D7 and with XE2, it runs like you want, as expected.

Comment: there is at least 1 bug with the splitter on XE5. I am testing a simple example of 1 panel/scrollbox containing 2 panels separated by 1 splitter, all 3 top-aligned (panel, splitter, panel). There is some "room" left on the container. Resizing down will leave splitter.minSize room on the container. Not only that, but resizing to minimum (upwards) which is drawn at splitter.minSize, makes the first panel disappear. If tehre is no room on the container, in case of a scrollbox, the splitter does not resize downwards. Tha same happens on panel, but you'd expect the scrollbox to resize itself.

Comment: Note to my above comment on panel disappearing: seems I had autosnap = true. I was sure I set it to false. But the rest is still going on.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi's alignment logic can be hard at times. But the following works. Note the line `splitter.Top := -1;`

```
function drawInput(owner: TWinControl): TWinControl;
    var
      panel: TPanel;
      edit: TEdit;
      splitter: TSplitter;
    begin
      splitter := TSplitter.Create(owner);
      splitter.Parent := owner;
      splitter.Align := alTop;
      splitter.Beveled := True;
      splitter.Height := 3;
      splitter.Top := -1;

      panel := TPanel.Create(owner);
      panel.Parent := owner;
      panel.Align := alTop;
      panel.AlignWithMargins := True;
      panel.BorderWidth := 0;
      panel.Color := clRed;
      panel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
      panel.ParentBackground := False;
      panel.Ctl3D := False;

      edit := TEdit.Create(panel);
      edit.Parent := panel;
      edit.Align := alTop;
      edit.AlignWithMargins := True;
      edit.Text := 'foo';
      edit.Margins.Left := 5;
      edit.Margins.top := 5;
      edit.Margins.Bottom := 5;
      edit.Margins.Right := 5;
    end;
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, same wrong order as in my example. Xe5 Upd2 here.

Comment: @cytrinox, Also note, that in my code I create the splitter first.

Comment: iamjoosy: yeah, I've copied the whole snippet, but has no effect.

Comment: @cytrinox, very strange. As you can see in the image, it works on my machine having used Delphi XE. It's hard ti image that Embarcadero would have changed something in the alignement logic.

Comment: @cytrinox, just checked with Delphi XE 7, and it works just as in my Delphi XE. Unless there is a specific change in XE 5, I think you must be doing something differently.

Comment: @iamjossy, I'ver updated the intial question with the snippet how I call this function. Can you try it?

Comment: @cytrinox, I see now, that in your example it doesn't work. Hmm, need to figure out what the difference is ...

Answer (score 0):

Position your panel + splitter then set the alignment
You can position you panel below all other components by aligning it to the client

```
function drawInput(owner: TWinControl): TWinControl;
var
  panel: TPanel;
  edit: TEdit;
  splitter: TSplitter;
begin
  panel := TPanel.Create(owner);
  panel.Parent := owner;
  ///
  panel.Align := alclient;
  ///
  panel.Align := alTop;
  panel.AlignWithMargins := True;
  panel.BorderWidth := 0;
  panel.Color := clRed;
  panel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  panel.ParentBackground := False;
  panel.Ctl3D := False;    


  splitter := TSplitter.Create(owner);
  splitter.Parent := owner;
  //
  splitter.top := panel.top+panel.height;
  //
  splitter.Align := alTop;
  splitter.Beveled := True;
  splitter.Height := 3;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, same wrong order. I've added one more call for getting 5 edits to make sure the code is really up-to-date...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works for me on XE5. I still have to solve my problem but at least I fixed yours :)

```
procedure drawInput(owner: TWinControl; var t: integer);
var
  panel: TPanel;
  edit: TEdit;
  splitter: TSplitter;
begin
  panel := TPanel.Create(owner);
  panel.Parent := owner;
  panel.Align := alTop;
  panel.AlignWithMargins := True;
  panel.BorderWidth := 0;
  panel.Color := clRed;
  panel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  panel.ParentBackground := False;
  panel.Ctl3D := False;
  panel.Top := t;
  t := panel.Top + panel.Height + 1;

  edit := TEdit.Create(panel);
  edit.Parent := panel;
  edit.Align := alTop;
  edit.AlignWithMargins := True;
  edit.Text := 'foo';
  edit.Margins.Left := 5;
  edit.Margins.top := 5;
  edit.Margins.Bottom := 5;
  edit.Margins.Right := 5;

  splitter := TSplitter.Create(owner);
  splitter.Parent := owner;
  splitter.Align := alTop;
  splitter.Beveled := True;
  splitter.Height := 3;
  splitter.Top := t;

  t := splitter.Top + splitter.Height + 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  form: TForm;
  sb: TScrollBox;
  t: integer;
begin
  form := TForm.Create(Application);
  sb := TScrollBox.Create(form);
  sb.Parent := form;
  sb.Align := alClient;
  sb.Color := clBlack;
  t := 0;
  drawInput(sb, t);
  drawInput(sb, t);
  drawInput(sb, t);
  drawInput(sb, t);

  form.Width := 300;
  form.Height := 700;
  form.ShowModal;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my applications, I have a function that creates a TImage and follows it with a TSplitter with the parent and containing control being a TScrollbox (sbScroller). The function is either called by the end user (tied to a TButton OnClick event) when they select an image or when the program starts it loads a previously loaded set of images each divided by a TSplitter.

It works when run alone by itself (creating one TImage + TSplitter pairing) or when run in a continuous loop to create multiple pairings. The key element in getting it to work seems to the positioning of the TSplitter.Top property as the previous answer says:

```
procedure AddImage(AFilename: string);
var
  Image: TImage;
begin
  Image := TImage.Create(sbScroller);
  with Image do
  begin
    Image.Parent := sbScroller;
    Left := 0;
    Top := 0;
    Width := 150;
    Height := 150;
    Constraints.MinHeight := 128;
    Align := alTop;
    Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
    Proportional := True;
    Stretch := True;
    Visible := True;
  end;
  if sbScroller.ControlCount > 0 then
    with TSplitter.Create(sbScroller) do
    begin
      Parent := sbScroller;
      Top := Image.Top;
      Align := alTop;
      Color := clGray;
    end;
end;
```