# How do I add Components dynamically during runtime in Builder XE6?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I want to add new panels to my form during runtime, but I have the problem that, when aligning them to the top, they are not displayed in the order that I created them.

I followed the hints from this post with the DisableAlign() and EnableAlign()
[How to dynamically create controls aligned to the top but after other aligned controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623347/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-aligned-to-the-top-but-after-other-aligned-co)
This works for the initial four panels I add.

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    TPanel * test;
    Panel1->DisableAlign();

    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        test = new TPanel(Panel1);
        test->Caption = i;
        test->Parent = Panel1;
        test->Align = alTop;
    }
    Panel1->EnableAlign();
}
```

[image: Screen 1]

But then I want to add another panel when clicking the button:

```
    void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        Panel1->DisableAlign();

        TPanel * test;
        test = new TPanel(Panel1);
        test->Caption = 5;
        test->Parent = Panel1;
        test->Align = alTop;

    Panel1->EnableAlign();
}
```

and this comes up:

[image: Screen 2]

Is there any way to get the alignment to do what I want without messing around with the Top Settings or without rebuilding the whole form?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. You must set `Top` to an appropriate value before setting `Align`. Set `Top` to be the coordinate of the bottom of the bottom panel.